# Beautiful Soup scraping all sublists until next large point

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently scraping a patent on Google Patents, and have scraped some of the information I need. However, some patents are formatted differently then others, for example, this patent
`https://patents.google.com/patent/EP3017304B1/en` has claim 1, and subpoints 2-6, until the next "big" claim 7. This patent, on the other hand, `https://patents.google.com/patent/AU2016304408B2/en`, has just the large claim 1, without any subpoints.

I am currently only looking to scrape claim 1, but if it has subpoints (like in the first patent linked), I want to retrieve those subpoints as well. For example, given the first patent, I want claims 1-6. Inspecting the page, I see that claims 2-6 have the class "claim-dependent", but I'm not sure how to retrieve all of the dependent claims up until the next "claim", which are claims 1, 7, etc.

This is my current code to only retrieve the first claim,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/AU2016304408B2/en'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(class_="claim")
claim_texts = results.find_all('div',{'class':'claim-text'})
fullStr = ' '.join([x.text for x in claim_texts])
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question well. You can use `.find_previous` to check if you want to add `<li class="claim-dependent">` to your output:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://patents.google.com/patent/EP3017304B1/en"
# url = "https://patents.google.com/patent/AU2016304408B2/en"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

# get first claim
claims = [soup.select_one("li.claim, li.claim-dependent")]

# (optionally) add any claim dependent to output
for claim_dependent in soup.select("li.claim-dependent"):
    if claim_dependent.find_previous("li", class_="claim") == claims[0]:
        claims.append(claim_dependent)

# print all
out = " ".join(c.get_text(strip=True) for c in claims)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
An aptamer-based electrochemical sensor for detecting a target molecule, comprising an electrode, wherein an aptamer is covalently bonded to or chemisorbed on said electrode, said aptamer forming a complex with said target molecule,characterized in thatsaid complex is encapsulated by a gelatine B matrix. The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to claim 1, wherein the electrode comprises a gold electrode or a composite electrode combining a polymeric material and electrically conducting particles. The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to claim 1 or claim 2, wherein the electrode is coated with gelatine type B. The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to any one of claims 1 to 3, wherein said target molecule is selected from the group consisting of interferon γ, cell growth factors, antigens, therapeutic drugs, diagnostic agents, antibiotics, toxins, vitamins, recreational drugs, catecholamines, metabolites, proteins and cells. The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to any one of claims 1 to 4, wherein the aptamer is a nucleic acid aptamer. The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to any one of claims 1 to 5, wherein said aptamer is 5'-SH-(CH2)6-AGC-AGC-ACA-GAG-GTC-AGA-TGA-CTG-AGG-GCA-CGG-ACA-GGA-GGG-CAT-GGA-GAG-ATG-GCG-3' or 5'-GTC-TCT-GTG-TGC-GCC-AGA-GAA-CAC-TGG-GGC-AGA-TAT-GGG-CCA-GCA-CAG-AAT-GAG-GCC-C-spacer-NH2-3'.
```

---

For the second URL it prints only first claim.

Comment: Hi Andrej! Thanks for your reply, the code is working for a lot of the patents I'm using it for. This patent however is not working: https://patents.google.com/patent/US8560271B2/en?assignee=Roche&after=priority:20010602&type=PATENT&num=100&sort=new, and I'm not exactly sure why. I'm getting the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'" for the line out = " ".join... The patent seems to follow the claim and claim-dependent structure, but claims seems to be empty from the error message.

Comment: @BernieZhu Try to add `div.claim` to `claims = [soup.select_one("li.claim, li.claim-dependent, div.claim")]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css selectors and the `find_previous` method. First, find the primary claim:

```py
primary_claim = soup.select_one('li.claim')
```

Next, find all of the dependent claims:

```py
secondary_claims = soup.select('li.claim-dependent')
```

Finally, filter the secondary claims for the ones that are connected to the primary claim:

```py
claims = [primary_claim]
for item in secondary_claims:
    if item.find_previous('li', class_='claim') == primary_claim:
        claims.append(item)
```

Printing `claims` on the given url:

```
[<li class="claim"> <div class="claim" id="c-en-01-0001" num="0001">
<div class="claim-text">An aptamer-based electrochemical sensor for detecting a target molecule, comprising an electrode, wherein an a
ptamer is covalently bonded to or chemisorbed on said electrode, said aptamer forming a complex with said target molecule, <b>characte
rized in that</b> said complex is encapsulated by a gelatine B matrix.</div>
</div>
</li>, <li class="claim-dependent"> <div class="claim" id="c-en-01-0002" num="0002">
<div class="claim-text">The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to claim 1, wherein the electrode comprises a gold electrod
e or a composite electrode combining a polymeric material and electrically conducting particles.</div>
</div>
</li>, <li class="claim-dependent"> <div class="claim" id="c-en-01-0003" num="0003">
<div class="claim-text">The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to claim 1 or claim 2, wherein the electrode is coated with
 gelatine type B.</div>
</div>
</li>, <li class="claim-dependent"> <div class="claim" id="c-en-01-0004" num="0004">
<div class="claim-text">The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to any one of claims 1 to 3, wherein said target molecule i
s selected from the group consisting of interferon γ, cell growth factors, antigens, therapeutic drugs, diagnostic agents, antibiotics
, toxins, vitamins, recreational drugs, catecholamines, metabolites, proteins and cells.</div>
</div>
</li>, <li class="claim-dependent"> <div class="claim" id="c-en-01-0005" num="0005">
<div class="claim-text">The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to any one of claims 1 to 4, wherein the aptamer is a nucle
ic acid aptamer.</div>
</div>
</li>, <li class="claim-dependent"> <div class="claim" id="c-en-01-0006" num="0006">
<div class="claim-text">The aptamer-based electrochemical sensor according to any one of claims 1 to 5, wherein said aptamer is 5'-SH-
(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>6</sub>-AGC-AGC-ACA-GAG-GTC-AGA-TGA-CTG-AGG-GCA-CGG-ACA-GGA-GGG-CAT-GGA-GAG-ATG-GCG-3' or 5'-GTC-TCT-GTG-TGC-GCC-
AGA-GAA-CAC-TGG-GGC-AGA-TAT-GGG-CCA-GCA-CAG-AAT-GAG-GCC-C-spacer-NH<sub>2</sub>-3'.</div>
</div>
</li>]
```

Comment: @bernie Just saw previous answer and comment. The reason the provided code does not work on the given url is that the structure of the html is different. There are no <li class='claim'> tags in the provided url.